# How do I set "Lock aspect ratio" to on by default in PowerPoint?

Tags: images, microsoft-powerpoint

In Winword, if I paste a picture and try to resize it, the aspect ratio is locked. In PowerPoint however, it is off by default:
[image]

How can I set the default to locked?

(the version is Microsoft 365 Apps for Enterprise, desktop version)

Comment: FWIW, in the consumer version of O365, I've tried three or four ways of inserting or pasting in images and in all cases Lock Aspect Ratio has been checkmarked. Are you using a web or desktop version?

Comment: Yes, I agree with Steve Rindsberg, I do not reproduce your issue. Do you use master to make presentations?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been fixed if you disable "Use smart cut and past" in Power Point Options.  To get to this setting click on File > Options > Advanced and then it is in the "Cut, copy, and past" section which is the second section from the top.

If your Aspect Ratio was locked before you copy it will be locked when you paste. If you Group or Ungroup everything gets unlocked.

This seems like a very basic option, MS seems to have the default of this option reversed from what would be normal operation.